# Why doesn't my berries and cream mint taste like strawberries and cream?

Tags: mint

I recently put a strawberries and cream mint plant into my garden, and it's doing well, but noticed that it doesn't taste much like strawberries and cream. Why is that?

Comment: This remember me discussion with some botanists: What it the smell of this herb? You get 20 different answers (really very different answers). We are not so good on describing tastes, and it a taste is not 100% like what we know, we are lost. [Remember every taste is a bouquet of flavors].

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi it is not just the difficulty in describing things, but also there is a wide range in our abilities to detect scent (which gives us the majority of what we call flavour) - _Platanus_ sp. smell of honey to me but my mother can't smell them. Responses differ highly too flowers of _Jasminum_ sp. smell highly faecal to me but other people love them.